# Python function not optimizing

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, computer-vision

I am trying to solve the problem of homography (Computer Vision) using the optimization technique instead of the DLT (Direct Linear Transform) method. The simple illustration of this cost function is here:
[Illustration of cost function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPKdY.png)

I have implemented this cost function in python as: -

```
def costFunc(H, p1, p2):
    cost = 0.
    H = H.reshape((3, 3))
    H_inv = inv(H)

    for i in range(0, p1.shape[0]):
        # Forward Transformation
        x = p1[i, :]
        x_dash = p2[i, :]

        x = numpy.reshape(x, [1, 3])
        x_dash_estimated = applyTransformation(H, x)

        diff = numpy.sum(numpy.square(numpy.subtract(x_dash_estimated, x_dash)))
        cost = cost + diff

        # # Inverse Transformation
        x = p2[i, :]
        x_dash = p1[i, :]

        x = numpy.reshape(x, [1, 3])
        x_dash_estimated = applyTransformation(H_inv, x)

        diff = numpy.sum(numpy.square(numpy.subtract(x_dash_estimated, x_dash)))
        cost = cost + diff
    return cost/p1.shape[0]
```

Here, H is the same as H matrix (but flattened to a 1x9 vector) from the image given and p1 and p2 are 4 corresponding pairs of homogeneous points. They are both a 4x3  matrix. The corresponding points between the images are given below:-

```
refPt = numpy.array([[[182, 267, 1], [119, 270, 1]],
                     [[264, 111, 1], [202, 110, 1]],
                     [[544, 92, 1], [479, 95, 1]],
                     [[329, 356, 1], [269, 357, 1]]])
```

Each row represents two corresponding points in the images. They are seperated into p1 and p2 as: -

```
p1 = refPt[:, 0, :]
p2 = refPt[:, 1, :]
```

The function `applyTransformation` simply applies homography to the input point. It is given as:-

```
def applyTransformation(H, points):
    output = numpy.zeros(shape=[points.shape[0], 3], dtype=numpy.int32)
    for i in range(0, points.shape[0]):
        temp = numpy.dot(H, points[i, :])
        temp = temp / temp[2]
        temp[0] = numpy.round(temp[0])
        temp[1] = numpy.round(temp[1])
        output[i, :] = temp

    return output
```

Now, when I try to minimize this function, I get stuck in some local minima and global optimal value is never achieved.
My optimization code is given below: -

```
initial_H = numpy.random.rand(3, 3) * 1.
initial_h = initial_H.flatten()
result =  optimize.minimize(fun = costFunc,
                             x0 = initial_h,
                             args = (p1, p2),
                             method = 'TNC')
```

Need some suggestions to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you please post *all* the relevant code? I.e. your `applyTransformation()` function is missing here. Similarly the shape/types of the input points are not given above.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I have updated  the question.

Comment: FYI, I would suggest editing the tags and remove `homography` and instead add `computer-vision` for visibility. `homography` has 14 followers, `computer-vision` has thousands.